# Can I claim Spouse Exemption if my wife was on B2 tourist visa?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, f1-student-visa, dependents

I was an F1 student in 2015. My wife stayed with me in California for 59 days during 2015. But she was on B2 tourist visa and NOT F2 dependent visa which she is NOW. For filing my tax returns for the year 2015, can I claim Spouse Exemption that F1 students are eligible for? I am an Indian national and earned income in 2015 through internships/TA.

I was of the opinion that we can claim spouse exemption only if the spouse was on a dependent visa. But while trying to file my tax through sprinttax, it doesn't care about spouse visa status for 2015. It just said "Current Visa Status". And my wife is currently on F2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only claim your spouses exemption on a 1040nr if both of the following apply to you:

- you are a [married resident of Canada or Mexico or married U.S. national or Married resident of South Korea](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040nr.pdf) or [married resident of India who is a student or business apprentice](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/inditech.pdf)
- you provided over [half of your spouse's support in the tax year](https://www.irs.gov/uac/Can-I-Claim-My-Personal-and-or-Spousal-Exemption%3F)

Your spouse's status doesn't matter. It sounds like you only provided support for her for 59 days, so I don't think you qualify.